# Python calling a function from another file - error

Tags: python, csv, pandas, import

I am attempting to call a function from another file called 'run_ES_15M_Trend_Identifier':

```
import sys 
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(r"C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Daily Tasks\Individual Trading\ES"))


from ES_15M_Trend_Identifier import run_ES_15M_Trend_Identifier
```

So the above function comes from the ES_15M_Trend_Identifier py file. I just ran that file from its own directory and it works perfect - modifies the dataframe, sends to csv. So the error isn't coming from the function itself. Instead I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name run_ES_15M_Trend_Identifier
```

I realize there might be something circular about this process from other SO posts, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

edit: I've also tried:

```
from ES_15M_Trend_Identifier import *

run_ES_15M_Trend_Identifier()
```

which gives the error:

```
NameError: name 'run_ES_15M_Trend_Identifier' is not defined
```

edit: Here's the function, which works when I run it in its own file:

```
def run_ES_15M_Trend_Identifier():
    # Do stuff to pandas dataframe, including some for loops that fill out additional columns - this function works on the original file    
    path_to_csv = "C:\\Users\\cost9\\OneDrive\\Documents\\PYTHON\\Daily Tasks\\Individual Trading\\ES\CSV\\15M\\Trend_Identifier\\ES_15M_Summary.csv"
    ES_15M_Summary_Reduced.to_csv(path_or_buf = path_to_csv)
```

[image: The two files are in the same directory]

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use double backslashes in a raw string. Either use a `r` string or use double backslashes, but not both. (Even though Windows accepts a file path with double backslashes; it's confusing for anyone who reads your code.)

Comment: Hey, I tried the suggestion you made Davy, unfortunately it brings up the error shown in the edited post above. And that function runs in the original file perfectly so I'm not sure what's going on

Comment: Please show your ES_15M_Trend_Identifier.py file. Does it definitely define something called run_ES_15M_Trend_Identifier?

Comment: Hey Daniel, okay, I updated

Comment: No classes, the only other text in the other file i'm importing from (besides the function above) is import pandas as pd. etc.

Comment: Type of file is .py - pic in op now

Comment: that returns 'NameError: name 'ES_15M_Trend_Identifier' is not defined'

Comment: aha oh man, I had to close the python editor and re-open, was some type of bug. I was wondering what was going on it looked right. Thanks for the help Davy, if I can give you rep points in some way let me know how!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is both files are in the same directory? if not put both files in the same folder!

Comment: Hi, they're in the same directory  - C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Daily Tasks\Individual Trading\ES

Comment: what happens when you comment sys.path.append line?